# unused parameter elimination optimization

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there an "unused function parameter elimination optimization", when I use enabler as following:

```
template< typename T >
void f(T x, typename std::enable_if< some_predicate< T > >::type * = nullptr) { /* do something useful with x */; }
```

?

I mean, will generate extra code for `void *` parameter passing (for example, for GCC 4.8 compiler)?

And what about in light of lto/ltcg presence?

Comment: Most likely, I would think, and you can always leave it unnamed to disable any warnings.

Comment: My question is about binary optimality of the generated code for modern compilers.

Comment: I expect modern compilers to optimize away the whole function call to such a function that does nothing, not just avoiding to pass an argument.

Comment: Assume, that the function body contains something useful.

Comment: @Dukales: You can always move the `enable_if` to the return type instead.

Comment: @K-ballo I think, that I can do it not in all cases.

Comment: In case of overloading of function with the signature with mutual exclusive cases in enabler's conditions, there is no such way.

Comment: @K-ballo: (Adding to what Dukales said) Another example is constructors which don't have a return type.

Comment: @CassioNeri I should note that I was unfortunately wrong. But as for the constructors it is true.

Comment: Dukales: This is tagged _C++11_, and in _C++11_ you can add template arguments with default values pretty much everywhere. You can use those to exercise _SFINAE_.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly, doing this violates the ABI, as far as I am aware- i.e., some other compiler that did not optimize might pass in a value there.

However, in my experience, Clang has an immensely irritating habit of removing parameters it views as redundant- especially values of empty types. So I would suggest that the compiler might do if it can prove the value is unused.